# how to send event(RPC) to service/application in nagios

Tags: nagios

I am using nagios to monitor certain services. I want to trigger event when particular services goes in error state. Lets say disk space is full so send event(like RPC ) to particular service which will resolve this issue.How to configure nagios to send such event ?

Answer (score 0):

In nagios, these are called [event handlers](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html).  You define a command and tell the service to run that under the proper circumstances.